# Firebase Realtime Database Setup Rules For Custom Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Real time database for our chat app and it's works fine until i try to set rules
right now i have unsecured rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Where anyone can write and read the entire database. So i generate custom token at user login then  sign in with FirebaseAuth.

```
mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(mCustomToken)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails
                    Toast.makeText(CustomAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                }
            }
        });
```

If i use Database reference without child `DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()` and rules like below then it's works without any issues

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
  }
}
```

and when i start adding children like this `DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");` then it showing `DatabaseError: Permission denied` in log. My app is live with users so it won't set rules for now because it will block our users to access database and chat.

This is my actual realtime database.

```
{
  "Chat": {
    "919810012345-919810012346": "",
    "919810012347-919810012348": {
      "-NI7hqW3YTFKpnSZU422": {
        "Message": "Test Message",
        "Message_From": "Demo User5",
        "Message_From_ID": "0001",
        "Message_To": "Test User",
        "Status": "Delivered",
        "Time": "1669814773643",
      }
    },
    "919810012345-919810012349": "",
    "919810012345-919810012350": {
      "-NI7hXybU02Mg6vYqdKp": {
        "Message": "Test Message",
        "Message_From": "Demo User5 ",
        "Message_From_ID": "0001",
        "Message_To": "Dummy User",
        "Status": "Delivered",
        "Time": "1669814693724",
        "Type": "Typed_Message",
      }
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "0001": {
      "Online": false,
      "lastSeen": "1671742997177"
    },
    "0002": {
      "Online": false
    },
    "0003": {
      "Online": false
    }
  },
  "UsersLocations": {
    "0001": {
      "-1": {
        "Latitude": "28.531",
        "Longitude": "77.257"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to set rules for above database structure?

Comment: Are you asking us to write the security rules for your fully defined data structure and code? That seems a bit beyond what's reasonable on Stack Overflow. Starting from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security (including the video) and https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules would be better for that. --- If you have a specific read or write operation that you tried to write rules for and can't get working, please update your question to show where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No i am not asking for code i am asking for hints or any kind of sample which can relate to my structure